# Writing to multiple directories in Spring Integration file adapter

Tags: spring, spring-integration

How can this be done? It works fine with one int-file:outbound-channel-adapter, but I could not make it work when I add another one. I actually added another, separate set of channel/adapter but it still did not work.

In int-file:outbound-channel-adapter tag, there is actually a "directory" attribute, but it only accepts a single directory path.

Here is the code I have tried:

```
    <int-file:outbound-channel-adapter id="outputDirectory1"
                                   directory="${output.directory1}"
                                   channel="fileWriterChannel1"
                                   filename-generator-  expression="headers.get('filename')"
                                   delete-source-files="true"/>

<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter id="outputDirectory2"
                                   directory="${output.directory2}"
                                   channel="fileWriterChannel2"
                                   filename-generator-expression="headers.get('filename')"
                                   delete-source-files="true"/>
```

Below are the channels, while the bean is the actual writer. Note that the two channels both refer to the bean (ref="messageTransformer"):

```
    <int:transformer id="messageToStringTransformer1"
                 input-channel="messageTypeChannel"
                 output-channel="fileWriterChannel1"
                 ref="messageTransformer"
                 method="write"/>

<int:transformer id="messageToStringTransformer2"
                 input-channel="messageTypeChannel"
                 output-channel="fileWriterChannel2"
                 ref="messageTransformer"
                 method="write"/>

<bean id="messageTransformer" class="com.message.writer.DefaultMessageWriter"/>
```

Comment: Please include a sample of the code you've tried, along with details of why it's not working for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I do understand you correctly, do you want to write a Message payload to a collection of directories simultaneously? In order to have multiple file adapters listen to the same channel, you have to use a *Publish Subscribe Channel* using the  element. For more information, please see: http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-configuration-pubsubchannel

When using a *File Outbound Channel Adapter*, you can also use the *directory-expression* attribute which is available since Spring Integration 2.2. It gives you full SpEL expression support. Thus, the directory you want to write to, can be for example a provided message header. For more information, please see:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/html/files.html#file-writing-output-directory

Comment: Yes Gunnar, that's what I want.

Comment: Great, it works! I used Publish-Subscribe channel, then used it in two Outbound Channel adapters.

`code`<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="fileWriterChannel"/>`code`